# Track Excel Cell Changes

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I wonder whether someone may be able yo help me please.

I'm using the code below to track Excel cell changes with the addition of inserting the text value of "No" in column "G" and the date of cell change in column "A"

```
Option Explicit
    Public preValue As Variant
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        Dim Cell As Range
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
            On Error Resume Next
            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B5:H10")) Is Nothing Then
            If Target.Value <> preValue And Target <> "" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Range("A" & Target.Row).Value = Date
            Range("G" & Target.Row).Value = "No"
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Target.ClearComments
            Target.AddComment.Text Text:="Previous Value was " & preValue & Chr(10) & "Revised " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & Chr(10) & "By " & Environ("UserName")
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 35
        End If
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

        If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Target = "" Then
            preValue = "a blank"
        Else: preValue = Target.Value
        End If
        preValue = Target.Value
    End Sub
```

What I'd like to be able to do is extend this a little further. So if the value in column "G" changes from "No" to "Yes" I'd like all cell shading to be removed from the cells on the same row in columns "B:G", but I'm not sure how to do this.

I just wondered whether someone may be able to look at this please and offer some guidance on how I may go about changing this.

Many thanks and kind regards

**Post Edit
Working Solution**

```
Option Explicit
Public preValue As Variant
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Rng As Range
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B5:W500")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value <> preValue And Target.Value <> "" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Range("A" & Target.Row).Value = Date
            Range("AX" & Target.Row).Value = "No"
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            'Target.ClearComments
            'Target.AddComment.Text Text:="Previous Value was " & preValue & Chr(10) & "Revised " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & Chr(10) & "By " & Environ("UserName")
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 35
        End If
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
            If Target.Column = 50 Then
                If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
                Set Rng = Application.Union(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "B").Resize(, 22), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "W"))
                Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                End If
                End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a quick question - Why not just use conditional formatting based upon column G's value?

Comment: Hi @John Bustos, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. Yes I did try Conditional Formatting with the following formula
`=OR($G5="Yes", $G5="")`. This worked and correctly removed the cell shading. However, something strange happened. Using row 5 as an example, if I removed the cell shading in columns B, D, and F using this formula, then I entered a value in column "C", columns "B", "D" and "F are shaded again even though the values in these haven't changed. I didn't understand why, so I was using this as a 'Work around'. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: ... Can you exlpain this a bit more? - From what I see in your code, if you changed C5, then G5 would change to "No", no?? - I'm just not sure I completely understand what you wrote in the previous comment...

Comment: My apologies for not making this clear. If I enter a value in B5,C5 & D5, they are correctly shaded with colorindex of "35" & all have the comment inserted. The value "No" is shown in G5 & the date is in A5. Conditonal Formatting for B5, C5 and D5 is set as follows: =OR($G5="Yes", $G5=""), so when I change G5 to "Yes", the cell shading is removed from these cells. However if I then enter a value in E5, not only is cell E5 shaded, but cells B5, C5, and D5 are shaded once more even though there has been no chage to these cells. I hope this helps. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: ... Your challenge is with this line of code `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B5:H10")) Is Nothing Then` - That will include column E and force G5 to get the value of "No", hence changing the shading.... If you are more specific on which columns you want to be looked at, we could change the code appropriately.... Hope that makes sense

Comment: Hi @John Bustos, thank you for your continued help with this. I think from the testing I've done, I think that there are two issues which I'd like to solve if at all possible please.
I hope this helps. Many thanks and kind regards.
The first is if the value in colum G is changed to "Yes" it removes the cell shading in columns B:G.

Then if a cell value is changed within this range, that only the cell which is being is shaded.

Comment: Ok, I can help you with this if you explain it in exact detail... so, you want: 1)If col G = anything other than "No" or blank, then remove all shading (and comments??) from all the cells in a:g  2)If a cell in the range b:f is changed ONLY that cell gets shaded and a comment is inserted and the timestamo is placed in col a... Is that EXACTLY what you want? Rule #1 in programming - BE PRECISE!!!!

Comment: Hi @John Bustos, thank you very much for your continued help with this. However, after trawling through the internet, I've now got this to work. I've included my solution in my original post. Many thanks and kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All, after trawling through the internet, I've now got this to work. I've included my solution below.

```
Option Explicit
Public preValue As Variant
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Rng As Range
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B5:W500")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value <> preValue And Target.Value <> "" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Range("A" & Target.Row).Value = Date
            Range("AX" & Target.Row).Value = "No"
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            'Target.ClearComments
            'Target.AddComment.Text Text:="Previous Value was " & preValue & Chr(10) & "Revised " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & Chr(10) & "By " & Environ("UserName")
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 35
        End If
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
            If Target.Column = 50 Then
                If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
                Set Rng = Application.Union(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "B").Resize(, 22), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "W"))
                Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                End If
                End If
End Sub
```